# How to write a query in groovy while the field value can be null or not null

Tags: sql, groovy

```
public boolean isDuplicateAccountMaterChartOfAccountsBySQL(MasterChartOfAccounts masterChartOfAccounts) {
    String query = """
        SELECT
            COUNT(mcoa.id) as mcoaCount
            FROM master_chart_of_accounts as mcoa
            WHERE
                mcoa.parent_account_id = ${masterChartOfAccounts.parentAccount?.id}
                AND mcoa.account_code = '${masterChartOfAccounts.accountCode}'
                AND mcoa.country_id = ${masterChartOfAccounts.countryId}
                AND mcoa.account_status_id = ${AccountsConstants.DOMAIN_STATUS_ACTIVE}
        """
    Sql db = new Sql(dataSource)
    List<GroovyRowResult> resultList = db.rows(query)
    return resultList.get(0).mcoaCount
}
```

here the field parent_account_id can be NULL or can be Not Null . But sql query doesn't work for a null value in this way . we have to write 
    where mcoa.parent_account_id IS NULL . 
So what can i do in the situation where the field can be NULL or Not NULL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
public boolean isDuplicateAccountMaterChartOfAccountsBySQL(MasterChartOfAccounts masterChartOfAccounts) {
    String query = """
        SELECT
            COUNT(mcoa.id) as mcoaCount
            FROM master_chart_of_accounts as mcoa
            WHERE
                mcoa.account_code = '${masterChartOfAccounts.accountCode}'
                AND mcoa.country_id = ${masterChartOfAccounts.countryId}
                AND mcoa.account_status_id = ${AccountsConstants.DOMAIN_STATUS_ACTIVE}
        """
    if (masterChartOfAccounts.parentAccount?.id) {
        query += " AND mcoa.parent_account_id = ${masterChartOfAccounts.parentAccount?.id}"
    }
    Sql db = new Sql(dataSource)
    List<GroovyRowResult> resultList = db.rows(query)
    return resultList.get(0).mcoaCount
}
```

Yes I solved it. :D